# Rspec doesn't clear factory objects after some specs

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot

Im using clear ruby (ruby 2.3.5) without Rails and ActiveRecord and trying to write specs for some service. And if I run only part of file (including problem spec), it passed. If I run the whole file - the problem spec is failed.

By the way, I already use rspec/retry, and it settings for 20 times retry (And I see in logs, that the problem spec is failed in all 20 times).

ballot_spec.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'spec_helper'
require 'byebug'

RSpec.describe Ballot do
  describe '#run' do
    let(:kingdoms) { build_list(:kingdom, 6) }
    let(:service) { described_class.new(kingdoms) }
    before { allow(service).to receive(:hold_ballot) }
    it 'holds ballot if cannot_finish_ballot? returns true' do
      allow(service).to receive(:cannot_finish_ballot?).and_return(true)
      service.run
      expect(service).to have_received(:hold_ballot).at_least(:once)
    end
    it "doesn't hold ballot if cannot_finish_ballot? returns false" do
      allow(service).to receive(:cannot_finish_ballot?).and_return(false)
      service.run
      expect(service).not_to have_received(:hold_ballot)
    end
    it 'returns Struct object' do
      expect(service.run.class.superclass).to be Struct
    end
  end

  describe '#hold_ballot' do
    let(:all_kingdoms) { build_list(:kingdom, rand(2..10)) }
    let(:pretendents) { all_kingdoms.first(rand(2..all_kingdoms.count)) }
    let(:message) { build(:message, from: all_kingdoms.sample, to: all_kingdoms.sample) }
    let(:expected_message_count) { pretendents.count * all_kingdoms.count }
    let(:new_service) { described_class.new(pretendents) }

    before do
      allow(Message).to receive(:new).and_return(message)
      allow(message).to receive(:send)
      new_service.send('hold_ballot')
    end

\/\/ THE PROBLEM IS IN THIS SPEC \/\/
    it 'prepares messages to all existed kingdoms from every pretendent' do
      expect(Message).to have_received(:new).exactly(expected_message_count).times
    end
    it 'only 6 of messages will be selected to be sent' do
      expect(message).to have_received(:send).exactly(6).times
    end
    it 'resets Kingdoms' do
      allow(Kingdom).to receive(:reset)
      new_service.run
      expect(Kingdom).to have_received(:reset).at_least(:once)
    end
  end
end
```

when I run rspec spec/services/ballot_spec.rb:26 (for test whole method '#hold_ballot') every spec is passed.
when I run rspec spec/services/ballot_spec.rb, I got failure:

```
  1) Ballot#hold_ballot prepares messages to all existed kingdoms from every pretendent
     Failure/Error: expect(Message).to have_received(:new).exactly(expected_message_count).times

       (Message (class)).new(*(any args))
           expected: 4 times with any arguments
           received: 260 times with any arguments
```

when I use byebug, I see, that class Kingdom has dozens of objects, but variables "all_kingdoms" and "pretendents" contains not more than 10 objects.

So the once rootcause I can see here - rspec doesn't clear kingdoms, created during testing method '#run', but how to push it destroy them? I don't use ActiveRecord, don't use Rails, so cannot tun "reload!" or "destroy" explicitly. Tried to run GC.start, but it doesn't help. What can I do? Many thanks! )

spec_helper.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require './models/kingdom.rb'
require './models/message.rb'
require './services/message_compose.rb'
require 'factory_bot'
require 'ffaker'
require 'capybara'
require 'rspec/retry'
require './spec/factories/kingdom.rb'
require './spec/factories/message.rb'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.verbose_retry = true
  config.display_try_failure_messages = true
  config.around :each do |ex|
    ex.run_with_retry retry: 20 unless ex.run_with_retry
  end
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
end
```

Comment: Have you tried using before :each instead of before :all?

Comment: Yes I have, but nothing changed

Comment: Please, show your spec_helper.rb file

Comment: Added spec_helper.rb to question body

Comment: Have you tried using this: https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner?

Comment: I have no database. Object initializing with build and therefore I don't use Database cleaner

Comment: you have both `allow(Message).to receive(:new).and_return(message)` and `expect(Message).to have_received(:new).exactly(expected_message_count).times` - you need to pick.

Comment: Clean your test database and then try setting the `use_transactional_fixtures` config to true https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions

Comment: Friends! Thank you very much, but let me remind you, there is no rails, there is no database. And this solutions doesn't work here (I tried) because it is for rails and database apps only.